# Connect to mongodb via mongoose no longer working in serverless nodejs functions

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, mongoose, serverless

In my serverless application I am connecting to a mongodb database. This has been in my application for months now, but just yesterday stopped working. It is working locally when using `serverless-offline` however. My connection code looks like this:

```js
// dabatase.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const connect = async (uri) => {
  try {
    mongoose.set("strictQuery", true)

    mongoose.connect(uri)
  
    mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
      console.log("Connected to database...");
    });
    
    mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', () => {
      console.log('Disconnected from database...');
    });
    
    process.on('SIGINT', () => {
      mongoose.connection.close(() => {
        console.log("Connection closed...");
        
        process.exit(0);
      });
    });
  } catch(error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}

module.exports.connect = connect;
```

And in my functions I am connecting to the database like this:

```js
const User = require("../models/User")
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs")
const _ = require("lodash")
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken")
const { connect } = require("../database")

connect(process.env.DATABASE)

module.exports.handler = async (event) => {
  let headers = {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": event.headers.origin,
    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true
  }

  ...other code
}
```

This has always worked and now I am getting 502 and CORS errors when trying to hit my endpoints in production. Things seem to work perfectly fine locally, but when deployed to AWS I always hit this error. Here are the cloudwatch logs:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In serverless you must first check if a connection exists, see mongoose guide:
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/lambda.html

I personally use `connect` and it never failed me:

```js
import { config } from "dotenv";
import mongoose, { Mongoose } from "mongoose";

config();

let conn: null | Promise<Mongoose> = null;

export const connect = async function (dbName?: string) {
  const parsedDbName = dbName || process.env.DB_NAME;
  const uri = `mongodb+srv://admin:${process.env.MONGODB_PASSWORD}@adyproduction.5cosb.mongodb.net/${parsedDbName}?retryWrites=true&w=majority`;

  console.log("Connecting to MongoDB...");

  mongoose.set("strictQuery", false);
  if (conn == null) {
    conn = mongoose
      .connect(uri, {
        serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 5000,
      })
      .then(() => mongoose);

    // `await`ing connection after assigning to the `conn` variable
    // to avoid multiple function calls creating new connections
    await conn;
  }

  return conn;
};
```

also make sure to connect on the handler, not in the external function, like this:

```js
import { connect } from "./helpers/mongo-connect";

const handler = async (event) => {
  await connect();

  // Rest of the code
}
```